# BufferedWriter does not flush

Tags: java, http, sockets, client-server, printwriter

I have the following problem....

```
            try 
            {
                clientInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                clientOutput = new BufferedWriter(new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));

                while(true)
                { 
                    String clientRequest = "";
                    String tempStr = clientInput.readLine();

                    while(tempStr != null && !tempStr.equals("null"))
                    {
                        System.out.println(tempStr);
                        clientRequest += tempStr + " ";
                        tempStr = clientInput.readLine();
                    }

                    //Parse Request
                    ArrayList<String> tokenArray = parseRequest(clientRequest);

                    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

                    switch(tokenArray.get(0))
                    {
                        case "GET": 
                        {
                            clientOutput.write("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n");
                            clientOutput.write("Date: " + c.getDisplayName(0, Calendar.LONG, Locale.UK).toString() + "\r\n");
                            clientOutput.write("Server: Java HTTP Server v1.0\r\n");
                            clientOutput.flush();
                            break;
                            //Write File
                        }
                        default: 
                        {
                            clientOutput.write("500\r\n");
                            clientOutput.flush();
                        }
                    }
                } 
            }
```

Every thing works completely fine up-and-till the `clientOutput.write("HTTP.......` line,
the client just keeps waiting and waiting... i've attempted to flush after every sucsessive write and yet nothing..... BUT This is the weird part - if i write to and flush before the code enters the while-loop the the writes in the `case "GET":` works perfectly...... ie

The code does execute all the way to the

```
                            clientOutput.flush();
                            break;
                            //Write File
```

.

```
              try 
             {
                clientInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                clientOutput = new BufferedWriter(new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));

                clientOutput.write("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n");
                clientOutput.flush();

                while(true)
                { 
                    String clientRequest = "";
                    String tempStr = clientInput.readLine();

                    while(tempStr != null && !tempStr.equals("null"))
                    {
                        System.out.println(tempStr);
                        clientRequest += tempStr + " ";
                        tempStr = clientInput.readLine();
                    }

                    //Parse Request
                    ArrayList<String> tokenArray = parseRequest(clientRequest);

                    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

                    switch(tokenArray.get(0))
                    {
                        case "GET": 
                        {
                            clientOutput.write("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n");
                            clientOutput.write("Date: " + c.getDisplayName(0, Calendar.LONG, Locale.UK).toString() + "\r\n");
                            clientOutput.write("Server: Java HTTP Server v1.0\r\n");
                            clientOutput.flush();
                            break;
                            //Write File
                        }
```

Here is the code for the client

```
        Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 1337);

        BufferedReader fromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        BufferedWriter toServer = new BufferedWriter(new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream()));

        toServer.write("GET index.html HTTP/1.1\r\n");
        toServer.write("HOST: 127.0.0.1\r\n");
        toServer.write("Connection: close\r\n");
        toServer.write("\r\n");
        toServer.write("null\r\n");
        toServer.flush();   

        while(true)
        {
            String ss = fromServer.readLine();
            if(ss != null && !ss.equals("null"))
                System.out.println(ss);
        }
```

Server Class: Strydom_A_201103578_P03

```
public class Strydom_A_201103578_P03
{
    Thread[] threadArray = new Thread[5];
    int ClientCount = 0;

    public Strydom_A_201103578_P03() throws ClientSizeExceededException 
    {
        ServerSocket httpServer = null;
    try 
    {
        httpServer = new ServerSocket(1337);
    } 
    catch (IOException ex) 
    {
        Logger.getLogger(Strydom_A_201103578_P03.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    while(true)
    {
        try
        {
            //Wait for connection

            Socket clientSocket = httpServer.accept();

            if(ClientCount < 5)
            {
                threadArray[ClientCount] = new Thread(new clientHandler(clientSocket));
                threadArray[ClientCount].start();
                ClientCount++;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ClientSizeExceededException();
            }

        }
        catch(IOException ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {

        }
    }
}

class clientHandler implements Runnable
{
    Socket clientSocket;
    public clientHandler(Socket clientSocket) 
    {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        BufferedReader clientInput = null;
        BufferedWriter clientOutput = null;

            try 
            {
                clientInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                clientOutput = new BufferedWriter(new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));

                clientOutput.write(" ");
                clientOutput.flush();

                while(true)
                { 
                    String clientRequest = "";
                    String tempStr = clientInput.readLine();

                    while(tempStr != null && !tempStr.equals("null"))
                    {
                        System.out.println(tempStr);
                        clientRequest += tempStr + " ";
                        tempStr = clientInput.readLine();
                    }

                    //Parse Request
                    ArrayList<String> tokenArray = parseRequest(clientRequest);

                    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

                    switch(tokenArray.get(0))
                    {
                        case "GET": 
                        {
                            clientOutput.write("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n");
                            clientOutput.write("Date: " + c.getDisplayName(0, Calendar.LONG, Locale.UK).toString() + "\r\n");
                            clientOutput.write("Server: Java HTTP Server v1.0\r\n");
                            clientOutput.flush();
                            break;
                            //Write File
                        }
                        default: 
                        {
                            clientOutput.write("500\r\n");
                            clientOutput.flush();
                        }
                    }
                } 
            }
            catch (IOException ex) 
            {
                Logger.getLogger(Strydom_A_201103578_P03.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } 
            finally 
            {
                try 
                {
                    clientInput.close();
                    clientOutput.close();
                } 
                catch (IOException ex) 
                {
                    Logger.getLogger(Strydom_A_201103578_P03.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
    }

    private ArrayList<String> parseRequest(String tempStr) 
    {
        StringTokenizer httpTokens = new StringTokenizer(tempStr, " ");
        ArrayList<String> tokens = new ArrayList<>();

        while(httpTokens.hasMoreTokens())
            tokens.add(httpTokens.nextToken());

        return tokens;
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws ClientSizeExceededException 
{
    new Strydom_A_201103578_P03();
}
```

}

```
public class TestClient 
{

public TestClient() 
{
    try 
    {
        Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 1337);

        BufferedReader fromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        BufferedWriter toServer = new BufferedWriter(new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream()));

        toServer.write("GET index.html HTTP/1.1\r\n");
        toServer.write("HOST: 127.0.0.1\r\n");
        toServer.write("Connection: close\r\n");
        toServer.write("\r\n");
        toServer.write("null\r\n");
        toServer.flush();   

        while(true)
        {
            String ss = fromServer.readLine();
            if(ss != null && !ss.equals("null"))
                System.out.println(ss);
        }

    } 
    catch (UnknownHostException ex) 
    {
        Logger.getLogger(TestClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } 
    catch (IOException ex) 
    {
        Logger.getLogger(TestClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}



public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    new TestClient();
}
```

}

Client Class: TestClient

Create a project( or 2) and run the files

Comment: I doubt you're even getting that far. Are you sure you're breaking out of the `while(tempStr != null && !tempStr.equals("null"))` loop?

Comment: ...Hi david... as stated everything works up and till there - i went through the code with the debugger - The server is writing the the complte header... and does get to the flush.....

Comment: Ahh, okay. I bet the client received all the data the server sent and just called `readLine` again. (You haven't sent a complete HTTP response. What are you expecting the client to do but wait for the rest of it?)

Comment: ...fair enough - but why would that only work if i add the two extra lines at the top of the while loop.... surely it should then also "stupidly" ;-} call `ReadLine` again.... please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: What precisely is the problem you are having? Is it that the client is getting stuck? Or is it the server?

Comment: the server accepts the request of the client and reads all data from the input stream. It test for a 'GET' and responds with the `OK 200` header. The client waits for a response, but if i remove the `write` and `flush` after the `clientOutput = new BufferedWriter(new Pr....`  line the client doesn't read the data from the stream

Comment: When does the client break the while loop?

Comment: The strongly suggests you're not getting to the `GET` case. (Or getting there after the client has given up waiting.)

Comment: ....please run the two classes above - and please not (if you will run them) that if in the `run` method directly after the declaration of the first two variables you add `clientOutput.write(" ");` and `clientOutput.flush();` the client will read the response from the server

Comment: ps thanks for all the help i really do appreciate it

Comment: You don't need to test for "null", only for null, and the blank line that ends the headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is the `PrintWriter`. It swallows exceptions. Change it to an `OutputStreamWriter`. Then you will see any exception that is being swallowed. In general you should avoid `PrintWriters` and `PrintOutputStreams` over a network. They swallow exceptions that you need to know about.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your inner while loop to look for the end of the client's request:

```
while(tempStr != null && !tempStr.equals("null"))
```

to:

```
while(tempStr != null && !tempStr.equals("null") && !tempStr.equals(""))
```

The client won't disconnect (causing a null) after it sends a request. It will give you a blank line to indicate the end of its request.

Reason why returning the response header right away is working? Maybe the client just reads the 200 and (eventually) disconnects? So when you are reading the client's request, it ends and you get a null eventually.

---

EDIT:

So running your code, it works fine for me. Both the client and server are sending and receiving both requests and responses. However, the server never disconnects (the client includes a `Connection: close` header) and the client continues to block on `readLine()`. Unsurprisinly, when I include the `write()` and `flush()` immediately after setting up the connection on the server-side nothing changes except I see `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` twice on the client's end. Maybe all you need to do is close the `clientSocket` in a `finally{}` block at the end of your `try/catch{}`?

Comment: That's what I thought, but he swears he's getting out of the `while` loop. (Also, that's not really the right test for the end of the request. That's the right test for the end of the request headers.)

Comment: i now added the clients code so you guys can see - I am sending a my own `"null"` to exit.....

Comment: @AidenStrydom I've appended my answer

Comment: ....Jon: this server is suppose to follow the HTTP protocol - i have not yet come as far as writing the sending the page to the client so i can't close the connection as yet - i should still be able to send and receive with out closing the sockets

Comment: @joh - did you add the extra two lines of code or did the client receive the response with the above mentioned code?

Comment: @AidenStrydom it works perfectly fine whether I add them or not, if I add them I simply get `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` twice on the client's end.

Comment: just noteworthy - i shall write the source all-the-way to the end and let you guys know - thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

So for the futhering of my now ended suffering - here is what i finally did....

I changed both the server and the clients readers from `BufferedReader/Writer` to `DataInputstream/OutputStream`.... And it works perfectly now - ! Thanks to everyone

Aiden

Answer (score -1):

Just do this and it will work..........

Add `true` **as the 2nd parameter** in the `PrintWriter`

`clientOutput = new BufferedWriter(new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true));`